# Is SharePoint must for Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs

We have a team of 10 developers and are exploring the possibilities of better Source Control. We currently user Source Control with VS.net 2008.

My question to you guys is, is Sharepoint a must when installing TFS apart from SQL Server?

Please do advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SharePoint isn't a mandatory requirement for using TFS.

SharePoint is for creating project-related web portals for managing collaboration, wiki, contacts and so on.

You'll need it if you want to use SQL Reporting Services with TFS.

Answer (score 1):

While SharePoint is not required it does enable a few nice features.

Such as the centralized document repository which and have workflows attached to them.

And as Matías pointed out it enables the reporting.